# IMAP Access to BCC field

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, imap

I'm currently using IMAP and trying to access my gmail mailbox with it. I'm fetching email details such as Subject, Email Body, CC email Addresses etc.

My issue is that i need to access the **BCC email addresses** as well. I'm not sure whether the BCC field could be accessed due to the fact that..

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdBf5.png) - I'm sending this email which could be seen in the screenshot below 
**(it has a BCC email address added which is highlighted)**

[image]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNxF9.png) - This is my C# Code, which shows the BCC email count to be 0

[image]

So basically my **question** is that

- Can the BCC email addressed can be fetched using IMAP? Any sort of help/hint would really be appreciated.

Comment: is it a sent mail or a received mail?

Comment: @bugFinder Received mail Yes.

Comment: Then it will be empty - thats the point of bcc

Comment: @bugFinder that was really helpful Thank you :D

Comment: Historically, bcc is empty in the recipients' copy. The sender's archive copy often contained bcc _and sometimes bcc was left in the version sent to the bcc'd recipients_. I remember a giant flamewar on one list about whether to reveal bcc'd addresses to all bcc'd recipients.

Answer (score 1):

The BCC field is available in the IMAP `ENVELOPE` structure, along with from, to, cc, sender and in-reply-to. It's usually empty since most software removes it when sending the message, but if you can see it in the gmail interface you'll also be able to see it via IMAP, in the same way as your existing code accesses from/to/etc.

See RFC 3501 page 77 for details, or look for `uid fetch ... envelope` in your IMAP library.

Comment: Note: With gmail-SMTP, since gmail automatically puts the copy the the Sent box, the BCC fields are missing in the archive copies too.